# CURL on PHP/Apache/Win 7 64bit

Tags: php, curl, windows-7-x64

can anyone help me with enabling curl?
I have copied libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll, php_curl.dll into windows folder, system32, syswow64, apache, added php folder into PATH but it doesn't work.
Any solutions?

Comment: Are PHP/Apache also 64-bit installations?

Comment: yes, and everything works, only curl not

Comment: If PHP is 64-bit, I suspect ssleay**32** is not the correct bitness. A 64-bit process cannot load and use a 32 bit DLL. Edit: I see the 64 bit version is still called ssleay32.dll(!) but still, check that the DLLs are actually 64-bit DLLs or you'll get exactly the effect you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem enabling cURL for my Apache24 on Windows 7 with PHP 5.6.5
This is what I did and fixed the problem.
Move to Windows\system32 folder:
libssh2.dll, php_curl.dll, ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll

Move to Apache24\bin folder
libssh2.dll

Uncomment extension=php_curl.dll

Comment: This actually works correctly. I got confused by these instructions initially as I was unsure where to find said files. Also you don't need to move, copy worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

add `extension=php_curl.dll` into php.ini file

Comment: There you will find a semicolon (;) before above line. Just remove it and save the change. That’s it!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your php_curl.dll with this dll

[Fixed curl extensions:](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/)